# Decrypt TrueCrypt containers using dm-crypt

Tags: 12.04, encryption, truecrypt, decryption, dmcrypt

Is it possible to decrypt TrueCrypt containers using dm-crypt?

I have some container files created with TrueCrypt and I just wanted to know if it's possible to decrypt them using dm-crypt so I can stop using TrueCrypt and use something more opensource like dm-crypt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can do [that](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Device_Encryption#Encryption_options_with_dm-crypt). I use an external harddrive and mount it on my Ubuntu installations with `cryptsetup`/`dm-crypt`. But you need to update your cryptsetup packages to version 1.6 to get this functionality. I used this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~rayanayar/+archive/cryptsetup) on older Ubuntu releases.

Mounting a container is no different from mounting an encrypted partition as one would expect:

```
$ sudo cryptsetup tcryptOpen testcontainer.tc testcontainer
```

Now a new disk shows up in Nautilus or the launcher and you can mount it via Nautilus or terminal if you like. I mounted the container via Nautilus.

```
$ mount | grep testcontainer
/dev/mapper/testcontainer on /media/livewire/F29F-27D2 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Don't forget to unmount the filesystem and the container itself after unmounting the filesystem:

```
$ sudo cryptsetup tcryptClose /dev/mapper/testcontainer
```

While a GUI only solution to mount such containers and partitions the same way you can mount LUKS partitions would be more comfortable, it is currently not possible as it seems.

---

Automounting via pam_mount also seems to be not possible at the moment.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. `sudo cryptsetup tcryptOpen testcontainer.tc testcontainer` give me `cryptsetup: Unknown action.`

Comment: @oshirowanen That sounds like you're using an older version. You need to upgrade the package (via the PPA I mentioned) if you use an older release than trusy.

Comment: Looks like I have `cryptsetup 1.4.1` installed.  Is that version too old?

Comment: Yes, you need version 1.6 at least. Really.

Answer (score 0):

I can see doing this if you want to use TrueCrypt from Windows while using dm-crypt from Linux for the same container.

Since you want to stop using TrueCrypt altogether, have you considered creating new dm-crypt containers and transferring your TrueCrypt data into the dm-crypt containers? Is there a reason you want to keep your containers in TrueCrypt format?

Comment: I don't know of a Windows program that can read LUKS partitions/containers. So compatibility to Windows might be the reason?

Comment: I need the solution to decrypt my truecrypt volumes and transfer them elsewhere. As such, the question is pertinent.