# Truecrypt wont install on ubuntu 64 bit

Tags: truecrypt

I have downloaded Truecrypt 7.1a 64 bit and extracted the file in the archive manager.
I have put  `./truecrypt-7.1a-setup-x64` into the terminal but it says no such file or directory exists. I have tried Truecrypt 7.2 as well, but the same happens.

What am I doing wrong, can someone take me through it?

Comment: Did you change to the directory where it's extracted? Also DO NOT USE 7.2. Besides, `cryptsetup` works with most Truecrypt volumes, and there's also Veracrypt.

Comment: I'm not even sure how to change directory or what that means. Forgive me i'm really new to ubuntu. what is cryptsetup?

Comment: I copied and pasted 'cryptsetup' into the terminal, something did happen..... and i gave it permission to use some space on the hard disk.  I can't find the new program however. Can someone help?

Comment: This explains how to use cryptsetup with TrueCrypt containers or volumes: [Decrypt TrueCrypt containers using dm-crypt](http://askubuntu.com/q/420749/40581) N.B.: This was written for 12.04, on 14.04 you don't need the PPA.

Comment: Thankyou guys for all your advice. Im still struggling unfortunately. I have looked through some of the other questions dealing with this and other people don't seem to have the problem im having, and can load the software quite easily. i have looked at the link 'Decrypt Truecrypt containers using dm-crypt' . and to be honest i just dont understand much of what it says. Perhaps another question i should ask

Comment: is ' could someone recommend an idiots guide to Ubuntu that can give me a basic understanding of it ;)

Comment: I just want to be able to encrypt hard drives and memory sticks to protect personal data. Its proving more difficult than i hoped it would be.

Comment: Use a file manager like nautilus to extract `truecrypt-7.1a-linux-x64.tar.gz` (right-click it and on the menu choose "extract"), then you can double-click the resulting `truecrypt-7.1a-setup-x64`. Or start learning how to use the shell and the whole power of cryptsetup! Besides, if you want to encrypt hard drives and memory sticks for use in Linux-only you'd better use the Linux tools instead of Truecrypt which is better if you want something Windows can use.

Comment: Double-clicking on the extracted file opens a new window, after some time loading, it stops and says there is a problem. that the file contains some invalid characters, that if I continue editing the file I could corrupt the document, it says I could try and use another encoding, but that ends the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you solved it by now, but just in case, here is the easy way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stefansundin/truecrypt
sudo apt update
sudo apt install truecrypt
```

Works fine for me on 16.04LTS 64bit